# Can't open port 443 for local network

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, port, firewall

I want to use my raspberry pi, which runs Manjaro ARM, as a server for my local network. I have a golang server running permanently using systemd services. However, I can't access the website from another computer in the network. I disabled iptables and nftables but it still did not work. The server is running and I can even access the website, but only when using curl on the pi itself.

A ping from another machine works fine but scanning the port with nmap fails (the port is marked as filtered)

My code worked fine on my laptop, which runs regular Manjaro, I was able to access the website from any device on the network (even though iptables was not disabled there)

`ss -lnt` outputs:

```
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port Process
LISTEN  0       4096           0.0.0.0:5355        0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  0       4096     127.0.0.53%lo:53          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  0       128            0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN  0       4096              [::]:5355           [::]:*
LISTEN  0       4096                 *:80                *:*
LISTEN  0       128               [::]:22             [::]:*
LISTEN  0       4096                 *:443               *:*
```

`curl -k https://andre-pi` outputs `<a href="/login">Permanent Redirect</a>` but only when run on the pi

Any suggestions what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

With which command have you tried to access the website with curl? And does the server listen to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I used `curl -k https://andre-pi` and the response was `<a href="/login">Permanent Redirect</a>.`

`ss -lnt` gives me this:
`LISTEN  0       4096                 *:443               *:*`

Comment: Can you ping your raspberry pi from another machine? Is there anything in the logs that you tried to connect?

Comment: Yes the ping works just fine, I can either use host name or ip, both works. There's nothing in the logs, just that I started the server and the connection attempt with curl. Also when I checked with nmap if the port was open (from another machine) the result was 'filtered'

Comment: Then please copy your code here and list which systemd services you are using. And sorry but I am not sure the firewall is really disabled

Comment: ```○ iptables.service - IPv4 Packet Filtering Framework
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled>
     Active: inactive (dead)```


```○ nftables.service - Netfilter Tables
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nftables.service; disabled>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:nft(8)```

Which code should I post?

Comment: You wrote you have a go server running? Didn't you mean a golang server? Perhaps there is ufw as firewall installed?

Comment: No, I dont have ufw installed, I checked that. The code for the server is about 400 lines. But it worked when I had the server running on my laptop and I could access the website from any device in the network, so I'm confident it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. There was another firewall I didn't know about called firewalld. I found it by going through all the installed packages with `pacman -Qqe` wich I piped through less.